# How to properly build Dictionary and access its elements?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having issues working with a Dictionary of Dictionaries in Python.

I am using these Dictionaries to produce the output below.

**Category**, and **Subcategory** are working correctly but **Group** is not.

My issue is that **Group** is breaking down the sales numbers of **Category** over and over again. I would like the **Group** to instead break down the sales numbers for the **Subcategory** it belongs to.

I am not sure if I am just building the dictionaries incorrectly, or accessing the elements incorrectly when adding the sales numbers.

I will post my code sample below the picture.

[image: Dictionary Output]

```
import pyodbc




# Define Levels Dictionary
Levels = {}

# Define Dictionaries for Category, SubCategory and Group
class All:
    def __init__(self):

        self.CatDICT = {}
        self.SubCatDICT = {}
        self.GroupDICT = {}



# FIRST QUERY CONNECTS TO DATABASE TO GET Category, Subcategory, Group DATA FROM TABLE CALLED MyTABLE
SQL = "SELECT MyTABLE.Category, MyTABLE.Subcategory, MyTABLE.Group FROM MyTABLE;"
cursor = pyodbc.connect("DSN=DATABASE_NAME;UID=DATABASE_ID;PWD=DATABASE_PASSWORD").cursor().execute(SQL).fetchall()

# This For loop adds Query information to appropriate dictionary
for row in cursor:
    if row.Category not in Levels:
        Levels[row.Category] = All()
        Levels[row.Category].CatDICT[row.Category] = {'SALES': 0}

    if row.Subcategory not in Levels[row.Category].SubCatDICT:
        Levels[row.Category].SubCatDICT[row.Subcategory] = {'SALES': 0}

    if row.Group not in Levels[row.Category].GroupDICT:
        Levels[row.Category].GroupDICT[row.Group] = {'SALES': 0}



# SECOND QUERY CONNECTS TO DATABASE TO GET Category, Subcategory, Group DATA AS WELL AS SALES NUMBERS FROM Orders TABLE
SQL2 = "SELECT MyTable.Category, MyTable.Subcategory, MyTable.Group, Orders.Sale FROM Orders INNER JOIN MyTABLE ON Orders.Parentsku = MyTABLE.sku;"
cursor = pyodbc.connect("DSN=DATABASE_NAME;UID=DATABASE_ID;PWD=DATABASE_PASSWORD").cursor().execute(SQL2).fetchall()

# THIS FOR LOOP ADDS SALES NUMBERS From the query TO EACH DICTIONARY
for row in cursor:
    if row.Sale != None:
        Sale = float(row.Sale)

    if row.Category in Levels:
        if Sale != None:
            Levels[row.Category].CatDICT[row.Category]['SALES'] += Sale
            if row.Subcategory != None:
                Levels[row.Category].SubCatDICT[row.Subcategory]['SALES'] += Sale
            if row.Group != None:
                Levels[row.Category].GroupDICT[row.Group]['SALES'] += Sale
```

Below is a snippet from the code above. It contains the code I use to create the dictionaries as well as the code I use to add sales numbers.

```
Levels = {}

# Category, SubCategory and Group dictionaries are defined here
class All:
    def __init__(self):

        self.CatDICT = {}
        self.SubCatDICT = {}
        self.GroupDICT = {}




# Query information added to appropriate dictionary, and Sales set to 0.
for row in cursor:
    if row.Category not in Levels:
        Levels[row.Category] = All()
        Levels[row.Category].CatDICT[row.Category] = {'SALES': 0}

    if row.Subcategory not in Levels[row.Category].SubCatDICT:
        Levels[row.Category].SubCatDICT[row.Subcategory] = {'SALES': 0}

    if row.Group not in Levels[row.Category].GroupDICT:
        Levels[row.Category].GroupDICT[row.Group] = {'SALES': 0}





# 2nd LOOP ADDS SALES NUMBERS From the query TO EACH DICTIONARY
for row in cursor:
    if row.Sale != None:
        Sale = float(row.Sale)

    if row.Category in Levels:
        if Sale != None:
            Levels[row.Category].CatDICT[row.Category]['SALES'] += Sale
            if row.Subcategory != None:
                Levels[row.Category].SubCatDICT[row.Subcategory]['SALES'] += Sale
            if row.Group != None:
                Levels[row.Category].GroupDICT[row.Group]['SALES'] += Sale
```

Comment: Please provide a smaller example of your problem, following https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: I created a snippet of the code to make it easier to read where dictionaries are being created and used. Hope this helps.

Comment: this part `Levels[row.Category].GroupDICT[row.Group]['SALES'] += Sale` always uses the same group, independently from which subcategory, if they have the same name. You have to use category and subcategory as a key for levels

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example of how I could use both category and subcategory as a key for levels?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this:

```
Levels = All()

# Query information added to appropriate dictionary, and Sales set to 0.
for row in cursor:
    if row.Category not in Levels.CatDict:
        Levels.CatDICT[row.Category] = {'SALES': 0}

    subKey = (row.Category, row.Subcategory)
    if (subKey not in Levels.SubCatDICT:
        Levels.SubCatDICT[subKey] = {'SALES': 0}

    groupKey = subKey + (row.Category,)
    if groupKey not in Levels.GroupDICT:
        Levels.GroupDICT[groupKey] = {'SALES': 0}
```

Honestly this can be simplified using 3 dictionaries, one for each level each or you could go with a tree like structure with dictionaries inside other dictionaries.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I will try this way, and let you know if I am able to get it to work.